# Meteor Server-to-Server: Connection handling and Method calls

Tags: javascript, performance, meteor

I searched a lot already but didn't find any real guide on that topic. So hopefully there is someone out here who can help.

**My setup**
2 apps connecting to the same backend (most likely there will be more than just one common backend in the future).

For simplicity let’s just consider having the app (that’s the frontend implementation) and the backend.

**Current status**
Establishing a connection and calling methods on the backend basically works. But I discovered the following issues.

**Issue: Setting up the connection**
When or where should the connection be set up? “Methods from a given client run one at a time” (see docs). If we connect to the backend on startup, we will use the same connection for every method call. This means that you should call this.unblock() from within the backend method or otherwise it would dramatically slow down the whole app the more users are connected to it.
To work around this I’m thinking of setting up a connection per user some how. But I don’t know how. Or connect on each method call.

What would be best practice here? Or which implications does each approach have?

**Issue: Calling a method**
Let’s assume we handled the connection stuff. Now we call a method on the backend connection.

How should the method be called? Sync or async?
How (and maybe that’s the most important question) can we handle the case when we lost the connection to the backend? This might be a common scenario.
My current solution for 2) would be to check the connection status on each method call. If Meteor.status().connected is equals false then I just throw a new Meteor.Error so the client could just tell the user to retry.

For some operations we might go with eventual consistency by waiting for the connection to reconnect. But that’s not the default case.

Comment: Did you already read into [DDP Connections](https://docs.meteor.com/api/connections.html#DDP-connect)? Before writing a large essay on ddp I would like to know wether you found anything there?

Comment: This is a very broad question and I just have to ask why you would want to complicate your life in this way? A much simpler pattern is to consider mongodb as "the back end" and build two apps (i.e. two matching front-ends and back-ends) that share a common db. That way both apps can share a persistent state but have unique business logic and front-ends. If you want to share the back-end business logic then you can encapsulate that into a *package* that both back-ends use.

Comment: @Jankapunkt yep, I did read into DDP. With what I read there I came up with the current solution described above.

Comment: @MichelFloyd Well, I have considered this approach too. The point why I didn't chose this approach is scaling. Different parts of the app will produce different load on the server or the database. So I wanted to keep the ability to separate things. E.g. a chat could be moved into a separate micro service.
With only having two frontend apps and one database for everything I'm quite limited in scaling. Of course I can scale everything, but this always affects the whole system.

Comment: Mongo can be horizontally scaled itself. Nothing prevents you from embedding microservices into a Meteor app over REST (or now GraphQL) but many Meteor *application* servers to many *client* applications is less obvious. You'll be in the deep end of DDP, session management, and auth.